# Why does nitrification -oxidation consume organic matter?

Tags: nitrogen-cycle

I want to express some doubts regarding autotroph bacteria.

The question I want to ask is relative to wastewater treatment plants, more precisely at the nitrification/denitrification step.

I've studied that nitrification doesn't need organic matter, in fact the latter is an inhibitor of the process. In addition, there are autotrophs bacteria employed, which comsume inorganic carbon for the processes.

But books of environmental engineering also mention that denitrification, if preceded by nitrification -oxidation, can present the issue of not having enough organic carbon for their processes, and that's the main reason we use post-denitrification systems today. Isn't it a contradiction? Why is organic carbon consumed by nitrification -oxidation, if they are autotroph bacteria? What am I missing in my reasoning? Do autotrophs in reality need organic carbon for their vital functions , and that was just omitted in calculations?

Thank you in advance